# How to deploy a jar built by spring-boot through maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, nexus

I use `mvn deploy` command to deploy my jar file to nexus server and it works fine for regular jar. But it doesn't work if the jar is packaged by `spring-boot-plugin`. The header of the jar file is a linux system service script which will be rejected by nexus.

Below is my spring-boot plugin settings:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

How can I make nexus accepts spring-boot executable jar file?

Answer (score 1):

Disable strict content type validation in your nexus server and you should be able to upload your jar. It can be found as below,

[image]

In administration, go to repository settings and disable this option.